# Group by with sort on more than million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization

I have a table with million+ rows. Each of them have a license no.

The query I have right now, does a group by on license no and sorts by count(Distinct(type)) and count(license_no) and date.

All the fields with joins - license_no or date are indexed.
But its taking me 5 seconds to return the results.

How do I speed up the performance. Ideally the results should not take more than a second.
Query:

```
SELECT `license_no`, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(type)) AS gdid, 
COUNT(id) AS cdid,
max(updated_on) as maxdate
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `license_no` >0 
GROUP BY `license_no`
ORDER BY `gdid` DESC, `cdid` DESC, maxdate DESC LIMIT 12
```

**Logic I want to implement:**

I have a list of cars (million + records).

I want to find all unique cars (unique by license_no)
sorted by :

- license_no which has max count of different types
- license_no which has max total counts
- finally sort individual records by latest date.

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want to implement.  Your query is malformed, because you refer to `updated_on` in the `ORDER BY`, but it is not defined in the `SELECT` and is not a `GROUP BY` column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have updated the query and the data which I want to fetch.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a sample of the desired output.  I do not understand "license_no which has max count of different types"

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to make this run fast is by pre-aggregating. You can do this using triggers on `mytable`. Your writes will be a little slower, but the query above will only need to scan a much smaller table.

Comment: More on Summary Tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: Without a lot more information its impossible to say if completing the query in under a second is possible. For now it is merely unlikely.